Ambiguity in Functioning of preprocessor and linker
pls someone clear my doubt that during compilation process preprocessor replaces the declaration of predefined function but not the defination then why we did not get error during compilation that function not defined as function defination is added to code after compilation in linking phase??
Pls someone tell what is the actual functioning of preproceesor and linking?

what do you mean? Preprocessor doesn't know anything about function declaration or definition

In short and very simplified, think of the preprocessor as a program that processes your source file before the actual compiler. It does copy-paste replacements of include files and macros. Very simple. Then the compiler takes the preprocessed source and compiles it into an object file. This object file is then passed to the linker, which adds other object files and libraries to create the final executable.

From my description, it should be clear (I hope) that the preprocessor doesn't actually know anything about the code itself, about statements, declarations or definitions. So please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the code you are wondering about, and give us more details.

preprocessor performs 3 task majorly:1. removes comments  2. expand macros   3. include the content of header files which contain the declaration of library functions

if preprocessor includes the header file content the what is the need of linker to link the object code of header files are they are already present in code

This seems like a good time for you to learn about the concept of translation units.
Summarized, a translation unit (or TU for short) is a single source file with all included header files. It's what the compiler actually sees, and it doesn't know anything about other translation units.
So if there's a declaration of a function, the compiler will know about that, but if the definition (implementation) is in another TU then the compiler will not know about that. The compiler can generate a call to the function, but leave a kind of note in the object file that there's a reference to a function in another translation unit.
This is where the linker comes in: It takes all translation units (object files) and libraries, and resolves references to functions in the different translation units.

Header files themselves are never "compiled" on their own, they are always included in the source files. Basically the code of the header file is copy-pasted into the source file.
So once the preprocessor is done, neither the compiler nor the linker knows anything about the header files. All they see are the single translation units.

thanks for the answer this clear my doubt as i have tried to use printf function without using #include<stdio.h>and just declaring printf() function with myself and i got the desired ouptput with warning..  But how in this case linker get to know that which file's object code it had to include as i have not added any header file

@KRISHNAKANTMALI As I said, the linker doesn't know about header files, at all. But the printf function is a standard C function, which is defined (implemented) in the standard C library that is linked by default. Therefore the linker will find the definition.

@KRISHNAKANTMALI Also note that there's only one standard C library, but it has many header files. But there could also be the opposite, where you have one (or more) header files, but no library, all the code needed is in the header file. So there's really no connection between header files and libraries that way.
